# How to initialize 2 dimensional array without '; expected' compiler error in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, initialization

I'm trying to simply initialize a 2D array:

```
string[,] keypad = new string[4, 3]{
            {"1", "2", "3"} ,
            {"4", "5", "6"} ,
            {"7", "8", "9"} ,
            {".", "0", " "}
        };
```

This sysntax is correct right? Why does my editor keep telling me '; expected', what am I missing?

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

When I mouse over the commas inside the brackets it tells me '; expected', when I mouse over the commas outside the brackets it gives me 'unexepected token'. I am using Jetbrains C# IDE Rider

Edit 2: It looks like cutting out and pasting the code back in fixed it. Must have been an IDE bug. Thanks for the help and sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce

Comment: Your code compiles fine....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is *correct*.

And I assume if you start the build process no compiler error will occur. Probably there is a bug in the Jetbrains C# IDE Rider and I suggest to open an issue at Jetbrains.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return at the end. I can't make out if you also are missing some opening/closing brackets elsewhere (the image is cut before your code finishes).

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Visual Studio. I had a similar problem, and restarting fixed it.